# Change image inside a div with class, id and other class qith Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image, class

I have a div with this structure:

```
  <div class="post" id="post-160439">
       <a href="http://site blablabla" title="blablablabllba">
       <img width="240" height="180" src="myimage.jpg" 
            class="attachment-240x180 wp-post-    image" alt="my alt" title="my title"></a>
  </div>
```

And I want to change the image on hover, I have (I think) the most part done, but can't get the point to change ONLY this image, not all images, Like this;

```
    $('.wp-post-image').attr('src','my new image');
```

it changes all images, how can I tell jquery to change a divID.wp-post-image?

Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of class name give a specific id to div and use `$('#id').attr('src','new image')`

Comment: can't modify the div structure, anyway, the div has an id, is it impossible to do it?

Comment: if you have static Id better use that instead of class.Cause class is not an unique attribute in the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#' + varHere + ' .wp-post-image').attr('src','my new image');
```

Comment: and... if the div ID is inside a var? ;)

Comment: @Mark Made the changes to include a var in the selector.

Comment: I'm having an issue, the page has several thumbs and I want them to change on mouse over, till now I reach to change only one, when I hover other thumb, the 1st thumb changes its image, and always the same, only the first

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple div's with images, you can try this:

```
  $('div .post').each(function(){
     $(this).find('img').hover(function(){
       $(this).prop('src','my new image');
     },
     function(){
       //  callback
      }
      );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster option:

```
$( document.getElementById( "post-160439" ) ).find( 'wp-post-image' ).attr('src','my new image');
```